# How to split a string to the left and right of a delimiter in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have text that I would like to split to the right and left using a delimiter. The text looks something like this:

This is text 10 : 12 More Text
Some1 14 : 10 MoreText

Output should be:

```
This is text | 10 | 12 | More Text
Some1 | 14 | 1 | MoreText
```

I have this formula but it doesn't work as it's supposed to.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="","",(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,"\s*(\d+)\s*","|$1|"),"|"))))

Link to Spreedsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmL4kzCGxRbwvNJntwMokqgt8yjjAqnZuUidTbZe6Z8/edit?usp=sharing

For example, it outputs the result of the second row above as `Some | 1 | 14 | 10 | MoreText`  when `1` is part of the `Some1` text. I just want the formula to split the text 4 spaces from the colon.

Please help me fix this, will appreciate.

Comment: Are you looking to use ":" as delimiter? or space (" ")? Or commas? You seem to be wanting multiple split operations with different delimiters in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

In this modification, I modified the regex and replace value of `REGEXREPLACE` from your formula.

#### Modified formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(\d+) : (\d+)","|$1|$2|"),"|"))))
```

- In this case, it supposes that the initial value of your sample value is put to the cell "A1:A9".

#### Result:

[image]

- The values of "A11:A12" are your sample input values in your question.

#### Note:

- I thought that `Myeam 4   5   Team D U18` in your sample might be `Myeam  74  15   Team D U18`.

#### Reference:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

### Added:

In order to remove the space of each cell, how about the following formulas?

#### Sample formula 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",(TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(\d+) : (\d+)","|$1|$2|"),"|")))))
```

#### Sample formula 2:

When I saw your sample input values, I confirmed that `00A0` is used as the space. So if your other sample values have it, please use the following sample formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="","",(TRIM(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(\d+) : (\d+)","|$1|$2|")," "," "),"|")))))
```

#### Reference:

- [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)

Comment: Your answer @Tanaike works perfectly except for the leading space created on the last column. How do you do away with that? Thanks.

Comment: @Mary ongubo Thank you for replying. About the trim of values, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?